# apt-get update Error

Tags: debian, apt, update, mod-security

I get the following error when typing:

```
# apt-get update

W: Failed to fetch http://etc.inittab.org/~agi/debian/libapache-mod-security2/etch/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 80.28.139.208 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

OS: Debian 7 Wheezy

Linux localhost 3.2.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 24 05:01:45 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Are you sure your OS is Debian 6? Have you installed a newer kernel by yourself? Debian 6 (Squeeze) comes with kernel 2.6.32, upcoming Debian 7 (Wheezy) or Debian testing/unstable has 3.2.0 ...

Comment: Sorry your right, it is Wheezy

Answer (score 3):

You try tu use an old (an inexistant !) repository (etch) with the release Wheezy.

Clean your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Then, try again `apt-get update`.

If you yant to install [libapache-mod-security](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libapache-mod-security), just try :

```
sudo aptitude install libapache-mod-security
```